# Nested Tabs in framework 7.

Tags: html-framework-7

I'm using framework7 for an app and although nested tabs are working as intended, I'm hitting a problem when trying to use nested swipeable tabs. 
My HTML/pug is as follows:

```
     f7-block
        f7-button.tab-link.active(href="#tab-1") GO 1
        f7-button.tab-link(href="#tab-2") GO 2
        f7-button.tab-link(href="#tab-3") GO 3
        .tabs
            #tab-1.tab.active
                f7-block
                    div TAB 1
                        f7-button.tab-link.active(href="#tab-1-1") GO 1 1 
                        f7-button.tab-link(href="#tab-1-2") GO 1 2
                        f7-button.tab-link(href="#tab-1-3") GO 1 3
                        .tabs-swipeable-wrap
                            .tabs 
                                #tab-1-1.tab.active TAB 1 1
                                #tab-1-2.tab TAB 1 2
                                #tab-1-3.tab TAB 1 3

            #tab-2.tab
                f7-block
                    div TAB 2
                        f7-button.tab-link.active(href="#tab-2-1") GO 2 1 
                        f7-button.tab-link(href="#tab-2-2") GO 2 2
                        f7-button.tab-link(href="#tab-2-3") GO 2 3
                        .tabs-swipeable-wrap
                            .tabs 
                                #tab-2-1.tab.active TAB 2 1
                                #tab-2-2.tab TAB 2 2
                                #tab-2-3.tab TAB 2 3
```

The second .tabs-swipeable does not work correctly and I can't find a way around this problem, any help would be greatly apprecited.

Answer (score 0):

It not works because of first `tabs` class.

According to the framework7 docs, swipeable wrapper class `tabs-swipeable-wrap` includes your tabs.

Refer to [this example](http://framework7.io/docs/tabs.html#swipeable-tabs) to see Tabs structure

HTML would be look like that :

```html
<!-- Navigation bar with buttons for tabs -->
<div class="tabs-swipeable-wrap"> <!-- global container -->
      <!-- tabs wrapper -->
      <div class="tabs">
        <!-- First tab -->
        <div id="tab1" class="page-content tab active">
         <!-- tab content -->
        </div>
        <!-- Second tab -->
        <div id="tab2" class="page-content tab">
          <!-- Tab content -->
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```